# How to call class init with tuples array parameter in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, tuples

I have the follow issue in my code:

```
class A {
    smth1: [[(Int,Int)]] = [[(1,2),(2,3)],
                            [(3,4),(4,5)]]

    var inst = B(smth2: smth1 [1])
}

class B {
    init (smth2: [(Int,Int)]){
    ...}
}
```

XCode generate error message: 
*Could not find an overload for 'subscript' that accepts the suplied arguments*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you should do it:

```
class A {
    let smth1: [[(Int,Int)]] = [[(1,2),(2,3)],
                                [(3,4),(4,5)]]

    @lazy var inst: B = {
        return B(smth2:self.smth1[1])
    }()
}
```

You cannot use instance properties before initialization/instantiation. I.e. there is no `self` hence no way to access `smth1` property, even if it is constant.

Alternatively you can declare `smth1` as class variable and access without `@lazy` initialization:

```
class A {
    class var smth1: [[(Int,Int)]] {
        return [[(1,2),(2,3)],[(3,4),(4,5)]]
    }

    var inst: B = B(smth2:smth1[1])
}
```